# Does a concurrent hashmap not require synchronized getters/setters?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

If i was using a concurrent hashmap and i had methods which set and got values, as im using a concurrent hashmap would i need to make the getter and setter synchronized? Is this redundant? Is one design better?

Also, is a concurrent hashmap without synchronization faster than a hashmap with synchronized getters and setters? This is for a high performance system

Thank you

Comment: what are you setting? Setting the values using put and get? Or creating the getter and setter for the hashmap itself?

Comment: Yes, my methods contain put and get.

Answer (score 7):

1. `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe
2. It is faster than using `synchronized(object)`
3. You still need to be careful not to create a "logical" race condition by code like this

   ```
   if (map.get(key) != null) {
       map.put(key, new SomethingStrictlyUnique());
   }
   ```
4. As a rule of thumb, replacing synchronized collections with concurrent collections can offer dramatic *scalability* improvements with little risks.
5. According to [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet%28%29), iterators returned by ConcurrentHashMap are "weakly consistent" (instead of fail-fast), so they tolerate concurrent modification, traverse elements as they existed when the iterator was constructed, and *may* reflect modifications to the collection after the construction of the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you've getter & setter methods which does only one operation (like get method will only return the map value for the given key) or any thread-safe operation, then you don't need an explicit synchronized block for those getter & setter.

2) Yes, using concurrent hashmap without synchronized block will greatly improve performance.

Note : ConcurrentHashMap is weakly consistent which is acceptable in most cases.