# Is it necessary to add the `volatile` keyword besides the `synchronized` one to make this class threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile, synchronized

First, I had the following (here simplifed) class:

```java
public class MyClass {

    private static Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static Object get(String key) {
        return objects.get(key);
    }

    public static void set(String key, Object object) {
        objects.put(key, object);
    }

}
```

Then, I wanted to make it treahsafe, so I tried the `synchronized` keyword as follow:

```java
public class MyClass {

    private static Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static synchronized Object get(String key) {
        return objects.get(key);
    }

    public static synchronized void set(String key, Object object) {
        objects.put(key, object);
    }

}
```

The question is, is the `synchronized` keyword sufficient in my case, or is it necessary to add the `volatile` one, i.e.:

```java
public class MyClass {

    private static volatile Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static synchronized Object get(String key) {
        return objects.get(key);
    }

    public static synchronized void set(String key, Object object) {
        objects.put(key, object);
    }

}
```

?

Comment: Everybody's recommending a concurrent hashmap, which will be threadsafe, but the documentation mentions a number of caveats about synchronization, which you may still need to synchronize to avoid.  Also, if you know the desired type of the stored object, you should be able to use 'generic' methods to be able to get an 'automatically cast' object (ie, the retrieval method does the casting, not the calling code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making `objects` volatile will only have an impact if you reassign `objects`. In your example you don't so it won't make a difference and is unnecessary.

Note that it is good practice to enforce "non-reassignability" by making `objects` final.

In your case, you could simply delegate thread safety by using [a thread safe map implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (which would certainly scale better than your synchronized implementation).

Comment: So you mean I should remove the `synchronized` keyword, and use `private final static Map<String, Object> objects = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();` instead, right?

Comment: @sp00m yes that would work (i.e. it would be thread safe too).

Answer (score 3):

`volatile` does not magically make your code thread safe, it's only here to prevent the JVM from doing optimizations that could not be relevant in a multithreading context (or worse, prevent your program from running as expected).

I suggest you take a look at [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) instead, it could be useful in your case.

Comment: So you mean I should remove the `synchronized` keyword, and use `private final static Map<String, Object> objects = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();` instead, right?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. Please take a look at this thread for further info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4702138/500478

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the reference that's stored in `objects`, so there's no value in using the `volatile` keyword.